# Authorize 3rd Party App to Access User Data from Laravel App

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I want to allow third party apps to access user data from my laravel application. But I am bit confuse how this process actually work.

I have installed laravel passport and its working fine. So what I am trying to do is:
3rd party app which has a unique client_id and secret can access any user data if user authenticate using his username and password.

I have used passport for user authentication for mobile devices. But accessing other user data, I am not sure if its possible with passport or not.

Answer (score 0):

Have a read through issuing access tokens: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#issuing-access-tokens. They give you in details all you need to get going. Though you will have to develop your own interface to allow your users to manage the clients they gave access to.

Once user gives access to  a 3rd party, they will then have access to that user's data because they will be part of the user's clients.

You should also watch this laracast https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13

Comment: thanks but I have already read and implemented this. Can you please look at my this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172792/laravel-passport-autenticate-user-before-authorize