# Laravel Passport Authenticate User Before Authorize

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am working on a project where 3rd party apps can access data from Laravel server. I also have created a client application in laravel for testing.

Following code ask for authorization and its working fine.

```
Route::get('/applyonline', function () {
$query = http_build_query([
    'client_id' => 5,
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://client.app/callback',
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'scope' => '',
]);
return redirect('http://server.app/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
});
```

How can I authenticate a user before authorization? Right now I can access data form server using this code.

```
Route::get('/callback', function (Request $request) {
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
$response = $http->post('http://server.app/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'password',
        'client_id' => 2,
        'client_secret' => 'fcMKQc11SwDUdP1f8ioUf8OJwzIOxuF8b2VKZyip',
        'username'=> 'ali@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'password',
    ],
]);

$data = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
$access_token = 'Bearer '. $data['access_token'];
$response =  $http->get('http://server.app/api/user', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' =>  $access_token
    ]
]);

$applicant = json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);

return view('display.index',compact('applicant'));
```

});

Although above code works fine but I don't think its a good way to ask username and password at client side.

I want to use this flow (Same as facebook allows)

- Click To Get Data From Server
- Enter Username and Password
- Authorize App
- Access data for authenticated user

Answer (score 0):

Well that was a stupid mistake. It works fine with authorization_code grant type. My mistake was that I was testing both server and client in same browser without logout. So client was accessing its own data from server. Also this flow diagram really helped me to understand the process of passport authorization.
http://developer.agaveapi.co/images/2014/09/Authorization-Code-Flow.png

```
 Route::get('/callback', function (Request $request) {
$http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;
$response = $http->post('http://server.app/oauth/token', [
    'form_params' => [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => 5,
        'client_secret' => 'fcMKQc11SwDUdP1f8ioUf8OJwzIOxuF8b2VKZyip',
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://client.app/callback',
        'code' => $request->code,
    ],
]);
return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);});
```